# Remove the @ from a twitter url?

Tags: php, regex

I've managed to figure out how to get the Twitter username out of a URL, but i need it to strip out the @ as well, which i'm not having much luck with.

```
$twitter_url = https://twitter.com/@twitter;

    if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?(?<name>[^\/]+)(\/\w+)*$/", $twitter_url, $regs)) {

                }

$twitterUsername = $regs['name'];
```

This is fine but its show as...

```
@twitter
```

When i just need it minus the @, i'm not 100% sure how to do this within the regex, can anyone help please?

Comment: `$twitterUsername = str_replace('@', '', $regs['name']);`

Comment: You don't actually need the `@` to start with, `https://twitter.com/twitter` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an optional `@` there before the `name` group:

```
'~^https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?@?(?<name>[^/]+)(/\w+)*$~'
                                       ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6PUi0V/1). So, if the `name` part starts with `@`, it will get consumed with the optional (but greedy) `@?` subpattern, and the `(?<name>[^\/]+)` will grab the rest of the URL subpart into `name` group.

Note the `~` regex delimiter might be more convenient here in order not to overescape the forward slashes inside the pattern.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/1jiQzJ):

```
$re = '~^https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?@?(?<name>[^/]+)(/\w+)*$~';
$str = 'https://twitter.com/#!/@tweet';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $m)) {
    echo $m['name']; // => tweet
}
```